# Too big value for double

Tags: java, double, range

How does Java handle a situation when a `Double` is assigned a value bigger than `Double.MAX_VALUE`?

Is there a standard behavior specified?

Comment: Have you just tested it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is defined in the [language specification #4.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4):

> A floating-point operation that overflows produces a signed infinity.

In the case of doubles, the result would be [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY).

Note however that if you try to assign such a large value to a double at compile time, you will get a compilation error:

```
double d = 1e100; //ok
double d = 1e300 * 1e300; //Double.POSITIVE_INIFINITY
double d = 1e900; //does not compile
```

If you need to handle very large numbers you can also use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the class BigDecimal is interesting for you. 
With theses classes you are able to calculate something outside the range of double.